# Cookie-parser, set cookie comes back as undefined

Tags: express, cookies

I authenticate and set a cookie with a unique id, i am using cookie-parser

```
app.post('/login'.... {
const sessionToken = uuidv4();

sessions[sessionToken] = {
    username: "test",
    expiresAt: expiredAt
}

res.cookie("AuthCookie", sessionToken, {expires: expiredAt })
res.redirect('/private');
}
```

//the value of sessionToken is  b821e069-6f54-4e50-8cbb-48f4244c24fb

when i try to access in my middleware

```
const withAuth = function (req, res, next) {

const sessionToken = req.cookies.AuthCookie; //undefined
console.log(sessions)
console.log("get user data",  sessions[sessionToken ])
}

app.get('/private', withAuth, (req, res ) => {
```

//is this happening because i'm not going through the browser?

Comment: If you are 'not going through the browser', what 'are you going through' instead?

Comment: I plan to go through the browser i was just doing this for testing, for example with they login they get redirected so it doesnt hit the client until the end

Comment: Well *something* needs to make a HTTP request with a cookie header. If you are not using a browser for testing, what are you using?

Comment: I guess i didnt explain correct the browser makes a request to the login page, i successful authenticated i res with a redirect to a private page, the private page doesn’t receive or recognjze the cookie i set.

Comment: Ok, take a look at your network tab. Does the `Set-Cookie` get sent with the _response_ to the redirect? Does the `Cookie` header get sent with the _request_ to the private page. You want to know if the browser didn't receive the cookie, or if it doesn't send it so we can narrow down where the problem may be.